# Unexpected conversion in regular initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

Clang 3.2 reports an error in the following code, and I do not understand why there is a problem. The error occurs only in the template function, and only if braces are used for initialization. The other two initializations work as expected.

```
struct foo {
    foo() { }
    ~foo() = default;
    // deleted
    foo(const foo& rhs) = delete;
    foo(foo&& rhs) noexcept = delete;
    auto operator=(const foo& rhs) -> foo& = delete;
    auto operator=(foo&& rhs) noexcept -> foo& = delete;
};

template <typename Type>
void bar() {
    foo a; // OK
    foo b{}; // ERROR
}

int main() {
    foo c{}; // OK
    bar<int>();
}
```

If I compile the code with `clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 -c`, Clang prints the following error message:

```
bug.cpp:14:9: error: conversion function from 'foo' to 'foo' invokes a deleted function
    foo b{}; // ERROR
        ^
bug.cpp:19:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'bar<int>' requested
      here
    bar<int>();
    ^
bug.cpp:6:5: note: function has been explicitly marked deleted here
    foo(foo&& rhs) noexcept = delete;
    ^
1 error generated.
```

I have no idea why Clang tries to do a conversion. It sounds like a bug. Unfortunately, I have the problem in a more complex code base, where the solution is not as easy as just removing the braces.

Why does Clang need a conversion in this case? And how can I get it working in general?

Comment: Looks like it works fine in clang 3.3

Comment: Why do you use `-> foo&` as trailing return on `auto operator=` instead of a regular return?

Comment: @rhalbersma: In new code I use trailing returns types basically everywhere. IMO it improves the readability of the code, because the function name is more important than the return type, and with C++14 the return type is optional with this syntax.

Comment: @nosid good point, forgot that return type deduction is coming soon!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is definitely a bug. There is no reason why an attempt should be made to invoke a move constructor, since you have a *default initialization*:

```
foo b{}; // Same as "foo b;" in any case
```

If *copy initialization* were involved, things would be different, but that is not the case.

Besides, your code compiles fine on GCC 4.7.2.

Comment: Good to know that is a bug in Clang. In this case I will stay with GCC 4.8 and maybe give Clang another chance in a few months.

Comment: @nosid: All right, good luck with your project. Btw, it seems that in Clang 3.2. this works